# Shoutcast DNA2 Read XML

Tags: shoutcast

I want to ask how i can readout the XML from shoutcast 2 ?

URL: IP:PORT/stats?sid=1

Now how i read the XML data and put the write the values down with php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Load the XML with DOMDocument.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Hi, Thanks has anybody an example to read out of the Shoutcast 2 XML ?

Answer (score 2):

Use SimpleXMLElement. You will do something like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents("http://{YOUR-SHOUTCAST_SERVER/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml&page=7&sid=".$sid."&pass=".$password"));
```

where $sid is your stream id and $password your stream admin password.

then extract the fields into variables like this:

```
$SERVERTITLE = $xml->SERVERTITLE;
$STREAMSTATUS = $xml->STREAMSTATUS;
$BITRATE = $xml->BITRATE;
$CONTENT = $xml->CONTENT;
$SERVERGENRE = $xml->SERVERGENRE;
$SERVERURL = $xml->SERVERURL;
$SONGTITLE = $xml->SONGTITLE;
$MAXLISTENERS = $xml->MAXLISTENERS;
$CURRENTLISTENERS = $xml->CURRENTLISTENERS;
$PEAKLISTENERS = $xml->PEAKLISTENERS;
```

The reason why I chose page 7 is because it contains the most stats on one page.

Answer (score -1):

```
$url = "http://ip:port/stats?sid=1";
$nice_url = urlencode($url);
$sc_stats = simplexml_load_file($nice_url);

echo $sc_stats->SERVERTITLE;
echo $sc_stats->BITRATE;
echo $sc_stats->SONGTITLE;
```

etc.